# How to read a string before a specific character appears

Tags: java

I'd like to read a string from `Reader` just before a character satisfying some specific conditions appears. I tried the following code:

```
private boolean isSatisfying(int codePoint) {
  return codePoint == '@' || codePoint == '$';  // for example
}

public String read(Reader reader) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (int codePoint = -1 ; (codePoint = reader.read()) != -1 ;) {
    if (isSatisfying(codePoint)) {
      break;
    }
    result.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

It works, but after executing `read()` the pointer of `reader` is at the character satisfying the condition (`@` or `$` in the example above), not at the end of the result string.

I want to keep the pointer of `reader` at the end of the result string, but there is no method of putting back the pointer of `Reader`.
Are there any good way to acheive it?

Answer (score 0):

Set your codePoint after you've added it in your for loop condition like this:

```
public String read(Reader reader) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (int codePoint = -1 ; codePoint ;) {
    if (isSatisfying(codePoint)) {
      break;
    }
    result.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
    codePoint = reader.read()) != -1;
  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Buffered reader to do this.  See the docs here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use **continue** instead of **break** (the result string won't contain the special characters but will process the whole file)

```
public String read(Reader reader) {
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (int codePoint = -1 ; (codePoint = reader.read()) != -1 ;) {
    if (isSatisfying(codePoint)) {
      continue;
    }
    result.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

If you dont want to process the whole file, then use **break** as you did but modify the return line.

```
return result.toString().substring(0, result.toString().length()-1);
```